# True picture in picture on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, window, gnome-shell-extension, extension

I am looking for an app that would provide true Picture in Picture, that is I'd be able to choose a section of a window (just like with screenshot) and that will create a small movable cutout of that window which will show it in real time. Somewhat similar to Windowspy, but I'm having problems with installing that ([https://launchpad.net/~vlijm/+archive/ubuntu/windowspy](https://launchpad.net/%7Evlijm/+archive/ubuntu/windowspy))
I know Ubuntu provides something similar but only for the entire window, not just a part of it. Elementary OS has exactly that.

Comment: FYI the [WindowSpy](https://launchpad.net/~vlijm/+archive/ubuntu/windowspy/+files/windowspy_0.5.9-1_amd64.deb) works normally (presenting whole window) at least on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS.